# A sequence is defined by the nth term: $n^3 -21n^2 +99n +121$. What primes does the sequence contain if continued to infinity?

Tags: sequences-and-series, distribution-of-primes

A sequence is defined by the nth term:
$$n^3 -21n^2 +99n +121$$

What primes does the sequence contain if continued to infinity?

(Question given by maths teacher in stretch and challenge workshop)

Comment: $n^3  - 21n^2 + 99n + 121 = (n+1)(n-11)^2$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $$a_n=n^3−21n^2+99n+121=\left(n+1\right)\left(n-11\right)^2$$
And for $n\ge 13$ both $n+1$ and $(n-11)^2$ are $>1 $ so $a_n$ is not a prime for $n\ge 13$.

Now you just want to check $n\le 12$ and see what primes the sequence gives.

Comment: As a further hint to OP: Since $a_n$ can be factored into two components, in order to be prime, one of them must equal $1$. One of the components is a square, so that must be the component that equals $1$. $(n-11)^2=1 \Rightarrow n-11= \pm 1$

Comment: Please read [Enforcement of Quality Standards, given your answer that is of very low quality](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C132.9382).